# Running Node.js depending on Operating System

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, macos, cross-platform

I am very new to programming AND Node.js but I have a question regarding running node.js apps on different Operating systems. I assume that it could happen that there are specific node modules which work only on a specifiy operating system. If I want to run my app for example on a linux server but I am developing on a mac and the linux server has no internet access how can I be sure that all node modules will run on my target os? As a result I am looking for a possibility to install node modulues dependent on an OS key. For example something like:

```
npm install module-name target-OS
```

After some research I found another possible solution: maybe I could define a script in the package.json file that will deal with this problem. Maybe something like:

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "authors": [
    "author <author@node.com>",
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dealwithos": "node bin/dealwithos.js"
  }
}
```

But until now i was not able to find any good code that would deal with this problem.

I hope somebody is able to provide some code or another possible solution!

Regards

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to believe that all modules won't work all OS's? This is a problem (if it is a problem at all) that's best solved case-by-case. Thinking about a general solution in advance isn't very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont believe that this problem will occur often but I am curious how i would fix it if it would occur and I am sure that there are some modules that will have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not really specific. Because of that there is no real correct answer. But I think that I can unserstand, what you want to know.

The main idea behing node.js is that it runs on all operating systems. Why? Because you are developing in JavaScript, which runs everywhere. Also most of all modules are written in JS. So if you are programming for a linux enviroment on your windows system you should ensure that the models you are using just written in JS. At all this is the normal node module.

Are there other modules?

Yes. It is possible to create modules by using C++. But there are not so many of them. If you want to use one of them you should read about the installation inside the docs of the module. At all you should also think about alternatives in JS. But it is not possible to answer that question in general.

There is also another way of node.js apps. For example [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) allows you to write apps in JavaScript. On this case you should read the [documentation about desktop integration](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.0/tutorial/desktop-environment-integration/). But that apps also have a gui. If you are developing just for node.js you won't have the gui part.

So just to answer your suggestion about os specific npm commands: No it makes no sense to install a module just for one operation system, because the idea of node.js is to be os independent.